# How to display the main window of a process in another Windows session?

Tags: windows, process, window, output

When running a Scheduled Task under Windows to launched batch processes under a dedicated account, you could want to see output of theses processes.

These sub-processes could be either or both graphical or character based applications

As there are running in a different Windows Logon session, I cannot find way to display their output. There are like ghost processes

I would expect being able to use the show Window command from Process Explorer, but even via running Process Explorer under the dedicated account used to run the task (via runas), it is not working

Is there a way to do it ?

References : http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/100/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that once created, a window cannot be transferred to another window station. Also, I doubt it is possible to open windows in another session. For character-based applications you are better off writing the output to some file and examining that file. For graphical applications you are out of luck with task scheduler. You may want to write a simple VBS script that wakes up at a certain time and runs your graphical task(s) and run it upon user logon, e.g. along the lines of a script from this page:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/d9465815-87e2-43df-a0fe-4a23c16dca99/need-a-time-schedule-in-vbs-script-to-execute-something